# How to prevent focus from being pulled by visual studio when starting an app?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console-application

Normally when I open a console app in visual studio I dont care about the console itself (the project is actually a service, but when run locally it runs as a console app).  I dont actually care what is happening on the console most of the time.  I usually am still looking at the code or other windows.

**Question**:  Is there a way to prevent visual studio from shifting focus from the app that is opening?  I hate typing in something else and all of a sudden a console window opens up and I have to switch back.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run the console application with the console hidden, try to change the `Output type` to `Windows Application`.

Here are the step:

`Project => Properties => Application => Output type => Windows Application`.

Now the console content will shown in VS `Output` window.